# Как удалить ключ реестра Windows с помощью ассемблера?

Tags: ассемблер, реестр, masm32, nasm, syscall

Мне нужно с помощью любого языка ассемблера (но желательно MASM или NASM) удалить какой-нибудь ключ реестра Windows. Как я понял, для этого нужно сделать или системный вызов (в случае MASM я не нашел, как это сделать, ведь там нет инструкции, подобной syscall), или использовать функцию из какой-то библиотеки. Итак, вот что я пробовал:

1. я попытался совершить системный вызов с помощью NASM, поместив в регистр EAX значение 212 (потому что в моей сборке Windows 10 такой номер у функции NtDeleteKey). Я не нашел официальной документации к этой функции (номер найден на неофициальном источнике), но нашел подобную функцию ZwDeleteKey. Но я не смог передать в нее параметры - потому что нужен дескриптор, а он получается из функции ZwOpenKey, а в ней один из аргументов является указателем на структуру, а у меня ноль идей как создать такое на языке ассемблера. И я не смог найти однозначного ответа на то, как вообще передавать аргументы - все через стек или часть через регистры (на разных источниках почему-то разные ответы)?
2. я пробовал подключать библиотеку на MASM с помощью инструкции include/includelib, но код не компилировался. А именно я писал это:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
include \masm32\include\advapi32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\advapi32.lib
```

И я не нашел этих файлов на своем компьютере. Каким образом они вообще подключаются? Нужно ли скачивать эти библиотеки? И когда использовать библиотечные функции, а когда системные вызовы? Как совершить системный вызов в MASM? И как же все-таки удалить ключ реестра Windows на языке ассемблера?

*нужно удалить именно ключ - то есть какой-либо раздел в реестре, следующий сразу за одной из одной из пяти директорий - HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT и т.д. Код на языке ассемблера мне нужен для того, чтобы сделать из него шелл-код и использовать для эксплуатации уязвимости "переполнение буфера" в рамках лабораторной работы.*

Comment: импорт `RegDeleteKey()` из advapi32.dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdeletekeya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> для этого нужно сделать или системный вызов (в случае MASM я не нашел,
> как это сделать, ведь там нет инструкции, подобной syscall), или
> использовать функцию из какой-то библиотеки.

Чтобы разобраться в теме, вам нужно установить отладчик WinDbg, и скачать справочник ["Гарри Неббет: Native API Reference"](https://ultradefrag.net/doc/man/Windows%20NT(2000)%20Native%20API%20Reference.pdf).

В справочнике найдёте описание большинства нативных API, а в отладчике можно будет просмотреть форматы всех структур, включая нужную для `ZwOpenKey()` "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES".

В поле **"RootDirectory"** этой структуры вы должны записать указатель на строку с разделом реестра типа "HKEY_CURRENT_USER", а в поле **"ObjectName"** указатель на структуру с unicode-строкой подраздела реестра. В логе отладчика видно, что на х64 размер этой структуры равен 30h байт - его прописываете в поле **"Length"**. Параметры функции `ZwOpenKey()` и константы атрибутов найдёте в справочнике Г.Неббета:

```
NTSTATUS ZwOpenKey(
   OUT PHANDLE            KeyHandle,
   IN  ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,    // <--- указать "KEY_ALL_ACCESS" 
   IN  POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes  );
----------------------------------------------

0: kd> dt _Object_Attributes -v
struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,   <------ 6 elements, 0x30 bytes
   +0x000  Length                   : Uint4B
   +0x008  RootDirectory            : Ptr64 to Void
   +0x010  ObjectName               : Ptr64 to struct _UNICODE_STRING (3 elements, 0x10 bytes)
   +0x018  Attributes               : Uint4B
   +0x020  SecurityDescriptor       : Ptr64 to Void
   +0x028  SecurityQualityOfService : Ptr64 to Void
```

Здесь нужно помнить, что на системах х64 параметры функциям передаются через регистры `RCX/RDX/R8/R9` (соглашение "fastcall"), а на х32 только через стек (stdcall). Если всё сделаете правильно, то с ~50-ой попытки должно всё получиться.

Номера системных вызовов отличаются не только на разных версиях Win, но даже на разных сборках Build внутри одной версии. Если нужна кроссплатформенность, то придётся вычислять номер `syscall` динамически, через поиск "адреса функции" в таблице-экспорта Ntdll.dll, и дизассма первых шести байт на предмет сигнатуры `b8` (см.вторую строку) - после неё и будет лежать слово со-значением номера `syscall`. Здесь выручает отладчик, логи которого представлены ниже (у меня Win7-x64, Build 6.1.7601):

```
0: kd> uf ZwOpenKey     ;//<--- Unassemble Function 
ntdll!NtOpenKey:
00000000`7774bc50  4c8bd1       mov     r10,rcx
00000000`7774bc53  b80f000000   mov     eax,0Fh   ;//<-- ZwOpenKey() = 16
00000000`7774bc58  0f05         syscall
00000000`7774bc5a  c3           ret

0: kd> uf ZwOpenKeyEx
ntdll!NtOpenKeyEx:
00000000`7774ca80  4c8bd1       mov     r10,rcx
00000000`7774ca83  b8f2000000   mov     eax,0F2h  ;//<-- ZwOpenKeyEx() = 242
00000000`7774ca88  0f05         syscall
00000000`7774ca8a  c3           ret
```

Когда функция отработает, в указанный вами аргумент "PHANDLE" она вернёт дескриптор ветки реестра, через который можно будет удалить её вызовом уже `ZwDeleteKey()` - номер этого вызова так-же знает отладчик:

```
0: kd> uf ZwDeleteKey
ntdll!NtDeleteKey:
00000000`7774c690  4c8bd1       mov     r10,rcx
00000000`7774c693  b8b3000000   mov     eax,0B3h  ;//<-- ZwDeleteKey() = 179
00000000`7774c698  0f05         syscall
00000000`7774c69a  c3           ret
```

А вообще, связываться с `syscall` не советую. Если шелл для своего процесса, лучше создавать его документированным кодом Win32-API. Всё-что для этого нужно - вычислить дельту в памяти, и поместить все строки в сам шелл, перепрыгивая их джампами. Правда размер при этом получается больше, но для учебных примеров это не критично, ведь главное в них сама техника создания.

Вот консольное приложение х64, чтобы продемонстрировать последовательность вызовов функций из либы "advapi32.dll". Код написан на ассемблере fasm. Чтобы воспроизвести его, нужно создать в разделе реестра **"HKCU"** дир для тестов **"TestSybkey"**, после чего запустить прожку. По окончании обновить окно реестра по F5, и созданная папка исчезнет. Если удалить из этого исходника лишнее (от метки start, и до exet), то получим бинарник в виде шелла для своего процесса.

```
format  pe64 console
entry   start
include 'win64ax.inc'
;//------------------
.data
Hndl     dd   0               ;// вернётся дескриптор ветки
subKey   db   'TestSybkey',0  ;// ветка реестра
;//------------------
section '.code' code readable executable
start:
;// Открывем ветку реестра, чтобы получить её дескриптор
        invoke  RegOpenKeyEx,HKEY_CURRENT_USER,subKey,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,Hndl
        or      eax,eax
        jz      @next
       cinvoke  printf,' Error code: %08x',eax
        jmp     @exit

;// Вырезать этот блок, если пишем шелл
@next: cinvoke  printf,' Delete key "HKCU\TestSybkey\" ???  y/n.. '
@inp:  cinvoke  getch
        cmp     al,'y'   ;// вдруг юзер передумает
        je      @yes
        cmp     al,'n'
        je      @ex
        jmp     @inp

;// Удалить ветку в разделе реестра
@yes:   invoke  RegDeleteKey,[Hndl],subKey
        or      eax,eax
        jz      @exit
       cinvoke  printf,' Error code: %08x',eax

;// Обязательно закрыть дескриптор, иначе раздел не удалится!
@exit:  invoke  RegCloseKey,[Hndl]

       cinvoke  getch
@ex:   cinvoke  exit,0
;//-------------------------------------
section '.idata' import data readable
library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll', advapi32,'advapi32.dll'
import  msvcrt, printf,'printf', scanf,'scanf', getch,'_getch', exit,'exit'
import  advapi32, RegOpenKeyEx,'RegOpenKeyExA',RegDeleteKey,'RegDeleteKeyA',RegCloseKey,'RegCloseKey'
```

Comment: Что-то по-настощему проклятое, лайк поставлю за это.